# How to place google adsense inside android Webview

Tags: android, webview, ads

Can anyone help me on how to show Native Ad inside a Webview Content after 2nd paragraph. Suppose I am loading static html page in a Webview. Is it possible to show native/google Ad Sense inside Webview html page at random position when user reading the content of page ads appear inside the content.

Answer (score 0):

Adsense is for websites Admob is for mobile apps.You can apply for a AdMob account, which is designed for use in apps.